# How to run different sql queries on different threads or as different processes using Java

Tags: mysql, database, multithreading, jdbc

I just want to know how can I run different SQL queries on separate threads or separate processes. Example:

If I send a SQL query (SQL1) from JDBC and if it takes a very long time to run, I should be able to send another SQL query (SQL2) which might take a smaller time to finish its execution. I want this query to run on a separate thread or a process so that it doesn't has to wait for the SQL1 to finish.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL JDBC driver (Connector/J) is thread save. So you can start two thread doing different things on the same database. Just start a different connection on each Thread. Take in mind, that a SQL Lock on thread1 could block thread2.

Simple example. Don't use the Old school `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`. JDBC4 will do that for you with the data from the connection URL. Main Thread will start both Threads and wait for both to finish. The two Threads are filled with dummy query.

```
public class TestThreads {
    public static class Thread1 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Connection connection = DriverManager
                        .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?"
                                + "user=myuser&password=mypassword");

                Statement statment = connection.createStatement();

                statment.executeQuery("select * from `table1`");

                [...]

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Thread2 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Connection connection = DriverManager
                        .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?"
                                + "user=myuser&password=mypassword");

                Statement statment = connection.createStatement();

                statment.executeQuery("select * from `table2`");

                [...]

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Thread2());

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        try {
            thread1.join(1000000);
            thread2.join(1000000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want ResultSet then write create different threads for different query. Execute is a blocking process. So you have to create different threads for running different queries in the same process.